# What is a black weapon?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have heard the term floating around as related to min-max damage increased weapons, especially in relation to the new ruby effects in the 1.07 PTR.

What is a black weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black damage on a weapon means there is no elemental affix damage to that item. IE: Fire, Cold etc.  It will have the min and max damage.  There is a bug with the calculations and a Black Weapon paired with a triumvirate for example will up your damage because you get the elemental affix's on that, it really boosts your damage.

Comment: its not a bug.  Any +% added elemental damage will use your weapon damage to calculate that % but only if the weapon is black

Comment: There is still that MinMaxDamage bug but they aren't going to try and fix it any time soon but if they do it will only affect the new created weapons.

Comment: that's not really a bug either.  When a weapon has adds 30-50 damage, its really equivalent to min 30 max 80, even though when we look at 30-50 we think it should be equivalent to adds min 30 max 50 damage.  Its unclear, but not a bug either.  But what IS a bug is that some add damage modifiers have a hidden damage modifier so it shows adds 10-20 damage but really adds 20-30 damage, etc.

Comment: Ahhhhhh sneaky buggers.