# Diablo 3 plus % elemental damage overall or just on that elemental attack?

Tags: diablo-iii

When an item says "+9% lightning damage" or something similar, does it mean I will get +9% damage regardless of whether I employ lightning damage as offense? Or does it just add the damage on top of what I already do?

If this will only add damage to lightning skills, what should I be looking for if I want added elemental damage when i'm not even using that particular element.

For example: Tal Rashas Set Bonuses for a Wizard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mixed bag.

1. If your weapon element matches the bonus elemental damage, OR if it is a [black weapon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103503/what-is-a-black-weapon).  The bonus is added to your attack.
2. If your weapon element does NOT match, you will not gain the bonus when using a non-elemental attack (for instance, using a fire weapon and casting magic missile will not give you the added +% lightning bonus).  This is mostly true but remember that weapons have a bit of base black damage so that may be added to the skill (you'll see a small up tick in DPS on your character).
3. If your weapon element does NOT match, BUT you use a skill that converts your damage to that element, you will get the % bonus for that skill attack.  (i.e. casting shock pulse while wielding a fire weapon gets you the % lightning bonus).